# How are related maven GAV naming an jar naming?

Tags: java, maven, jar

For the following GAV defined in my pom.xml:

```
groupID : org.test  
artifactID : test-spring-kie  
version : 0.1.8-SNAPSHOT
```

I have an exception when my java program looks for a maven resource:

> org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.test:test-spring-kie:pom:0.1.8-SNAPSHOT in local (file:///home/superseed77/.m2/repository)

or

> org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.test:test-spring-kie:jar:0.1.8-SNAPSHOT in local (file:///home/superseed77/.m2/repository)

I believe it's a reference to a jar named
`test-spring-kie[some separator]0.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar`
in the directory 
`.m2/repository/org.test/test-spring-kie/`

Am I right ?

What is the mechanism (transformation rules) to find jar name and location against this `org.test:test-spring-kie:jar:0.1.8-SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: Have you written a program that uses Aether?

Comment: no it's a kieScanner that uses it (drools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory hierarchy is :group/:artifact/:version/jarfile.

For example, commons-lang 2.4 is in the following location:

```
~/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
```

If you're using Maven to build your jar file you should really do `mvn install` to ensure it is placed in the correct location